# Hash в режиме онлайн

Tags: javascript

Имеется код на странице:

```
$(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('.product__tabs-class').fadeOut(0);
    if(hash == '#spec') {
        $('.product__tabs-item').removeClass('product__tabs-item_active');
        $('.product__tabs-item[data-tab="product__spec"]').addClass('product__tabs-item_active');
        $('.product__tabs-class').fadeOut(0);
        $('.product__spec').fadeIn();
    } else if(hash == '#reviews') {
        $('.product__tabs-item').removeClass('product__tabs-item_active');
        $('.product__tabs-item[data-tab="product__reviews"]').addClass('product__tabs-item_active');
        $('.product__tabs-class').fadeOut(0);
        $('.product__reviews').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.product__tabs-item').removeClass('product__tabs-item_active');
        $('.product__tabs-item[data-tab="product__store"]').addClass('product__tabs-item_active');
        $('.product__tabs-class').fadeOut(0);
        $('.product__store').fadeIn();
    }
});
$('.product__tabs-item').on('click', function() {
    var hash = $(this).data('hash');
    window.location.hash = hash;
    $('.product__tabs-item').removeClass('product__tabs-item_active');
    $(this).addClass('product__tabs-item_active');
});
```

Как заставить данный код реагировать на хеш в режиме реального времени, а не после перезагрузки страницы?